# Incorrect GROUP BY/HAVING statement causing unexpected results

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-2012, group-by, having, having-clause

I have the following query that is not producing the expected results.  I converted this from an Access query and there is a HAVING clause in the Access query that I cannot seem to replicate in my SQL.  The HAVING clause contains the code relating to the field, Eval Date.  I tried adding that code to a HAVING statement in my SQL, but it did not make a difference in the output.  How can I properly group this query?

```
DECLARE 
@CurrentYear smallint,
@CurrentMonth date,
@Period varchar(3),
@Division varchar(2)

SELECT
@CurrentYear = DATEPART(YY, GETDATE()),
@CurrentMonth = EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1),
@Division = 'BT'

SELECT @Period = dd.FiscalPeriod
FROM dbo.DateDimension dd (NOLOCK)
WHERE dd.LastDayOfMonth = @CurrentMonth

SELECT
    SupplierNumberBS = REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(pm.[Suppl ID], '0', ' ')), ' ', '0'),
    Period = @Period,
    FY = @CurrentYear,
    Division = @Division,
    pm.Country,
    pm.PCat,
    PMCTValidation1 = pm.[Supplier Status PMCT] + pm.[ES (Supplier)],
    pm.[Eval Date],
    pm.[End Date],
    pm.Evaluator,
    PMCTEValuationStatus =
        CASE
            WHEN pm.[Eval Date] IS NOT NULL THEN 'Completed'
            WHEN pm.[ES (Supplier)] = 'R' AND pm.[SEval (Project)] = 'R' THEN 'Overdue'
            ELSE 'Upcoming'
        END,
    PMCTStarRating =
        CASE
            WHEN pm.Score IS NULL THEN 0
            WHEN pm.Score >= 90 THEN 5
            WHEN pm.Score >= 80 THEN 4
            WHEN pm.Score > 70 THEN 3
            WHEN pm.Score >= 50 THEN 2
            ELSE 1
        END,
    pm.[Overdue Date],
    pm.[Eval ID],
    pm.[ES (Supplier)],
    bb.BranchOffice,
    bb.Zone,
    pm.[Project ID],
    pm.Score,
    pm.NCC,
    pm.[NCC Amount],
    pm.PM,
    SupplierNameBS = pm.[Suppl Name],
    pm.Comment,
    pm.[Comment Problem],
    pm.Problem,
    pm.Purchasing,
    pm.Logistics,
    pm.[Quality and EHS],
    pm.Technology,
    pm.[Devel Status],
    OpenSupplierNCC = pm.[NCC 1]-[NCC Recovered],
    pm.[NCC 1],
    pm.[NCC Recovered],
    pm.Name,
    pm.[Root Cause],
    pm.[Comment Action],
    pm.Claim
FROM
    dbo.BTPMCT pm (NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN dbo.BTBuyerBranch bb (NOLOCK) ON pm.[Branch Number] = bb.BranchNumber
WHERE
    pm.[Supplier Status PMCT] + pm.[ES (Supplier)] <> 'InactiveR'
AND
    pm.Country = 'CA'
AND
    pm.[Eval Date] >= DATEADD(MONTH, -14, GETDATE())
OR
    pm.[Eval Date] IS NULL
GROUP BY
    REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(pm.[Suppl ID], '0', ' ')), ' ', '0'),
    pm.Country,
    pm.PCat,
    pm.[Supplier Status PMCT] + pm.[ES (Supplier)],
    pm.[Eval Date],
    pm.[End Date],
    pm.Evaluator,
    pm.[SEval (Project)],
    pm.[Overdue Date],
    pm.[Eval ID],
    pm.[ES (Supplier)],
    bb.BranchOffice,
    bb.Zone,
    pm.[Project ID],
    pm.Score,
    pm.NCC,
    pm.[NCC Amount],
    pm.PM,
    pm.[Suppl Name],
    pm.Comment,
    pm.[Comment Problem],
    pm.Problem,
    pm.Purchasing,
    pm.Logistics,
    pm.[Quality and EHS],
    pm.Technology,
    pm.[Devel Status],
    pm.[NCC 1],
    pm.[NCC Recovered],
    pm.Name,
    pm.[Root Cause],
    pm.[Comment Action],
    pm.Claim
HAVING
    pm.[Eval Date] >= DATEADD(MONTH, -14, GETDATE())
OR
   pm.[Eval Date] IS NULL
ORDER BY
    pm.[Eval Date] DESC
```

Here is the original Access query:

```
SELECT [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[Supplier number-BS], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].Period, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].FY, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].Division, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].Country, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].PCat, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[PMCT Validation 1], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[Eval Date], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[End Date], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].Evaluator, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[PMCT Evaluation Status], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[PMCT Star Rating], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[Overdue Date], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[Eval ID], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[ES (Supplier)], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[Branch Office], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].Zone, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[Project ID], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].Score, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].NCC, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[NCC Amount], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].PM, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[Supplier name-BS], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].Comment, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[Comment Problem], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].Problem, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].Purchasing, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].Logistics, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[Quality and EHS], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].Technology, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[Devel Status], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[Open Supplier NCC], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[NCC 1], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[NCC Recovered], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].Name, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[Root Cause], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[Comment Action], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].Claim
FROM [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R]
GROUP BY [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[Supplier number-BS], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].Period, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].FY, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].Division, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].Country, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].PCat, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[PMCT Validation 1], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[Eval Date], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[End Date], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].Evaluator, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[PMCT Evaluation Status], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[PMCT Star Rating], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[Overdue Date], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[Eval ID], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[ES (Supplier)], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[Branch Office], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].Zone, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[Project ID], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].Score, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].NCC, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[NCC Amount], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].PM, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[Supplier name-BS], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].Comment, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[Comment Problem], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].Problem, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].Purchasing, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].Logistics, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[Quality and EHS], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].Technology, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[Devel Status], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[Open Supplier NCC], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[NCC 1], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[NCC Recovered], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].Name, [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[Root Cause], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[Comment Action], [qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].Claim
HAVING ((([qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[Eval Date])>=DateAdd("m",-1,DateAdd("m",-12,Month(Now()) & "/" & [Forms]![Period Form]![txtFiscalYear])) And ([qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[Eval Date])<DateAdd("m",-1,DateAdd("m",-12,Month(Now()) & "/" & [Forms]![Period Form]![txtFiscalYear]))+365)) OR ((([qry - BT PMCT CA - A - Inactive R].[Eval Date]) Is Null));
```

Comment: First off, you should put parentheses around the components of your WHERE clause, to make sure that the conditions are being evaluated the way you intend.  Second, you need to provide sample data (simplified to only the relevant columns) and examples of your current behavior and what you consider to be "expected behavior".  Finally, we need the "HAVING" clause, which I don't see in the query you posted.

Comment: I added the HAVING clause.  Can you show me what you mean by putting parentheses around the components of the WHERE clause?

Comment: Read this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186992%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Please also post the original Access query.

Comment: The issue was with the use of parentheses in the WHERE clause.  Thank you for that help.